# CSS Issue with the footerwrapper

Tags: css, margins

I can't figure out why I am unable to get my footer wrapper and the elements inside to center up with the rest of the page. I'm using this code and it is not working:

`#footer-wrapper{
    margin:0 auto;
}`

If someone has a minute and can take a look, I would appreciate it. http://skeeterz71.com/auto/

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? What is the rest of the code and the relationship with your HTML to this CSS? If you could add the code to a pen or fiddle that would help future users when your site changes.

Comment: the footer wrapper is located inside of my outer-wrapper like everything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're aligning content with `margin: 0 auto;` you need a set-width because divs are automatically 100% which basically means the width of the window which means there's no space to center.

Also, it's better for the wrapper to be within a parent.

**See this:** http://jsfiddle.net/cranavvo/zKMD5/

Answer (score 0):

Add the rule `.row .row{ margin-left:0; margin-right:0; }`